# Change text hover

Tags: css

How change text when I push cursor in button? If I push cursor in button with price, will show text: "Add to basket".

This is Code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
}
.price {
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.price:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  color: #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="price">$50</div>
<div class="info">Add to basket</div>
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You want to hide `div.info` and have it show when, exactly?

Comment: Keywords: adjacent sibling combinator/general sibling combinator `.price:hover + .info { ... }`

Comment: The idea was to make the text appear on this button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:active` to show text when mouse is clicking down on the price like so:

```css
.price {
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.price:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    color: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info {
    display: none;
}

.price:active + .info {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="price">$50</div>
<div class="info">Add to basket</div>
```

if you are trying to show the text on `:hover` like the title of the question says the unser `:hover` like so:

```css
.price {
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.price:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    color: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info {
    display: none;
}

.price:hover + .info {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="price">$50</div>
<div class="info">Add to basket</div>
```

Update 3:

```css
.price {
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.price:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    color: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info,
.price:hover .amount {
    display: none;
}

.price:hover .info {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <div class="amount">$50</div>
  <div class="info">Add to basket</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The idea was to make the text appear on this button.

Comment: @overFlow can you explain "make the text appear on this button"? Cause there is no real button, what happens to `$50` when the `Add to basket`  appears over it? Can the width change?

Comment: I need change text inside the button. With: "$50" to "Add to basket"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper div to catch the over, I think is more maintainable if you change the html in the future:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
}
.price {
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.price:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  color: #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.info {
  display: none;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper:hover .info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="price">$50</div>
  <div class="info">Add to basket</div>
</div>
```